# Why is my sepcial RTL layout still aligned to left?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I have RTL layout and LTR layout.

at the beginning all works great, but after moving to Alerter mode

both layouts are aligned to left.

how can I fix this? or at least better inspect the situation?

is there any tool with which I can see the current layout properties and attributes in my Activity's view? The code changes many attributes from the original XMl and it's hard to follow at a specific situation.

here is my xml:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navBarBox2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navBarDistanceLayout"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/navBarDistance"
                style="@style/NavBarDistance"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:text="miles"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/navBarDistanceUnit"
                style="@style/NavBarDistUnit"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:text="0.1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" 
                />
        </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/navBarDistanceLayoutRtl"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <MyTextViewType
                    android:id="@+id/navBarDistanceUnitRtl"
                    style="@style/NavBarDistUnit"
                    android:textSize="19dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    />

                <MyTextViewType
                    android:id="@+id/navBarDistanceRtl"
                    style="@style/NavBarDistance"
                    android:textSize="19dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is parts of the code:

the change to AlerterMode and then coming back to non-alrter more makes `navBarDistanceLayoutRtl` be aligned to left instead of right

```
            if (bIsAlertMode)
            {

...
                if (rtlMode)
                {
                    width = view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayoutRtl).getWidth();
                    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams DistanceBar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    DistanceBar.setMargins(3, 20, 3, 0);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayoutRtl).setLayoutParams(DistanceBar);
                }
                else
                {
                    width = view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayout).getWidth();
                    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams DistanceBar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    DistanceBar.setMargins(3, 20, 3, 0);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayout).setLayoutParams(DistanceBar);

                }

...

            }
            else
            {
   ...

                if (rtlMode)
                {
                    width = view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayoutRtl).getWidth();
                    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams DistanceBar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    DistanceBar.setMargins(20, 8, 3, 0);

                    DistanceBar.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT;

                    view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayoutRtl).setLayoutParams(DistanceBar);

                    view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayoutRtl).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    distance = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceRtl);
                    distanceUnit = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceUnitRtl);
                }
                else
                {
                    width = view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayout).getWidth();
                    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams DistanceBar = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    DistanceBar.setMargins(0, 8, 3, 0);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayout).setLayoutParams(DistanceBar);

                    DistanceBar.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT;

                    view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayoutRtl).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    distance = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistance);
                    distanceUnit = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.navBarDistanceUnit);

                }

                ...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity` can use only for content inside of `LinearLayout`, `TextView` or other Views. if you want to RTL or LTR layout you have to use `android:layout_gravity`.

Comment: i need to change programatically. How to change `DistanceBar.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT;` ?